# I can't import a text data file into SQL Server 2008 with the import wizard

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, integration

I have a problem while importing a text data file into a SQL Server 2008 database, the text file structure like this:

```
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
```

Every time I try to import the text file, it creates an error

Answer (score 0):

in management studios, rightclick on database, go task --> select import data. following the wizard steps by clicking next. In choose data source, select flat file source. Click on the browse button to point to the location of the text file. Click on next, in the "choose a destination" make sure ur sql server is selected. click next again. **The important part** in the "select table source", if you have a table existing that you want to import to, select the table from destination. Else sql server will create a table with the same name as your text file name.  Click next and finish.